# Is this regular expression for some property in VB 6: iif (integervariable, 0, 1)?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, integer, iif

Is this regular expression for some property in VB 6:

```
iif (integervariable, 0, 1)
```

If it is i want to know how does iif resolve integer argument without any logical comparisons?

Comment: Search for `regular expression` and then search for `msdn iif vb6` ..

Answer (score 6):

It's not a regular expression, it's a function call, with `IIf` being the function.

It's possible to use integer variables in boolean context in VB. In that case `0` translates to `False` and non-zero to `True`.

Answer (score 4):

Thats the `IIf` function. Check [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445024%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) about it.

Usually, in this programming language, 0 is for `False` and anything else for `True`.

In any case, "You should never write code that relies on equivalent numeric values for True and False." (MSDN)
Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae382yt8.aspx) in "Boolean Type Does Not Convert to Numeric Type Accurately" for more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. BTW I edited your link to point to the English VB6 docs on IIf. Your original link was to the Spanish VB.Net doc :)

Comment: @MarkJ Thanks. Sometimes my brain didn't realize the language he is reading. :P

Comment: "You should never write code that relies on equivalent numeric values for True and False." from MSDN, right? I disagree since bit-wise operations evaluate to a numeric value i.e.
`Dim i As Integer`
`i = 4 And 6 ' 4`
`if i then foo() else bar()`
My example is pretty much equivalent to a common bit-wise mask operation i.e.
`if (4 And 6) then foo() else bar()`

Numeric <-> boolean should be demystified. Programmers need to understand what @SysDragon pointed out about 0 = False and anything else = True.

Answer (score 1):

GSerg and SysDragon has some good answers.
I only wanted to add one thing not mentioned:

Whenever you have IIF or IF with no logical comparison such as

```
IIf (integervariable, 0, 1)
```

or

```
If (integervariable) Then ...
```

logical comparison to `True` is implied. So

```
IIf (integervariable, 0, 1)
```

is the same as

```
IIf (CBool(integervariable) = True, 0, 1)
```

and

```
If (integervariable) Then ...
```

is the same as

```
If (CBool(integervariable) = True) Then ...
```

Please note: as SysDragon mentioned, you should never rely on code that compares numeric values with boolean. This is why:

`Print IIF(CInt("123"), True, False)` is `True`

`Print IIF(CBool("True"), True, False)` is also `True`

So one would assume when comparing both of them the result would be True. But in fact,

`Print IIF(CInt("123") = CBool("True"), True, False)` comes out as `False`

The moral of this example is, if `integervariable` is an integer (or any other data type that is not a boolean), then it is best practice to have a logical comparison. In your case, instead of `IIf (integervariable, 0, 1)` use `IIf (integervariable <> 0, 0, 1)` instead. The result is the same with no potential unpredictable results.